# Comparing rows with multiples keys that might or might not be present in 2 Excel sheets

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, apache-poi

I need to process 2 Excel files which I need to compare in order to get those registers that are not present in both tables. Each register is identified by 4 component: the 4 last digits of an account, the card number, the authorization and the amount of the transaction. The problem I'm facing is that while one of the files contains all of this component, the other one does not, leaving holes in the register, as such is not guaranteed for them to be unique. I'll include an example:

File 1 with holes where I don't have data:

| ACCOUNT | TC | AUTO | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***456*** | ***0*** | ***98846*** | ***2302*** |
| 0 | 4797 | 0 | 79268599 |
| 782 | 8415 | 38711 | 78636161 |
| 0 | 0 | 61658 | 199234 |
| 506 | 0 | 0 | 1029249 |
| 0 | 0 | 50724 | 33554244 |
| 782 | 0 | 12308 | 28755261 |
| 956 | 0 | 0 | 9392043 |
| 396 | 3238 | 0 | 2482527 |
| 614 | 4442 | 0 | 30846962 |
| 855 | 0 | 71143 | 61793724 |

File 2 with all the information:

| ACCOUNT | TC | AUTO | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 861 | 4797 | 19313 | 79268599 |
| 782 | 8415 | 38711 | 78636161 |
| 410 | 1022 | 61658 | 199234 |
| 506 | 6368 | 93040 | 1029249 |
| 785 | 2478 | 50724 | 33554244 |
| 782 | 4741 | 12308 | 28755261 |
| 956 | 2623 | 45025 | 9392043 |
| 396 | 3238 | 14196 | 2482527 |
| 614 | 4442 | 61568 | 30846962 |
| 855 | 5917 | 71143 | 61793724 |

As you can see in this case Id need to return this value:

| ***456*** | ***0*** | ***98846*** | 2302 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Is there an efficient way I can do this either in SQL or using Java data structures? Is important to note that values might be missing from either one of the files. I was thinking about uploading them to a temporal data base, but that seems rather inefficient and I wanted to use a Map that supports the query operation I want with possible repeated values. Thank you for your help!

I tried this query, but it isn't returning no information and I'm not sure about creating a temporal database table, is there a map implementation that supports values with several keys being some of them optional?

```
select e1.id
    , e2.id 
from excel1 e1 
left join excel2 e2 on 
    (
        e1.Cuenta = e2.Cuenta 
        OR 
        e1.TC = e2.TC 
        OR e1.auto = e2.auto
    ) 
    AND e1.monto = e2.monto 
where e1.id not in 
(
    SELECT e1.id 
    FROM excel1 e1 
    WHERE id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT e1.id 
        FROM excel1 e1 
        LEFT JOIN excel2 e2 ON 
            (
                e1.Cuenta = e2.Cuenta 
                OR 
                e1.TC = e2.TC 
                OR e1.auto = e2.auto
            ) 
            AND e1.monto = e2.monto
        GROUP BY e1.monto 
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )
)
AND e2.id = 
    (
        SELECT e2.id 
        FROM excel1 e1 
        WHERE id NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT e1.id
            FROM excel1 e1 
            LEFT JOIN excel2 e2 ON 
                (
                    e1.Cuenta = e2.Cuenta
                    OR 
                    e1.TC = e2.TC
                    OR
                    e1.auto = e2.auto
                ) 
                AND e1.monto = e2.monto
            GROUP BY e1.monto 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
    )
```

Comment: I cleaned up that query so it is more legible. Sadly it makes me cry. I can't read this and understand what you are trying to do at all. There are so many duplicate subqueries in this. I am 99.99999% certain this can be great simplified but I can't figure out what the logic is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @Racertop Your question is well-formatted and you made an effort. Although, I think you need to split your problem into multiple smaller tasks and solve them one by one